# On the fly text color change in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

Does anyone know how to change the color of selection done in command prompt window on the fly? I forgot the key sequence which used to allow that.

I am not talking about changing the color permanently like with `color` command which changes color of all the text.

For example visit this page: [Check Command Prompt Window screenshots](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/jorge/archive/2006/12/09/DSA_2D00_GUIDs-and-Invocation-IDs.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows XP this should do the trick. [Download **Tweak UI** from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx), then:

1. Start Tweak UI.
2. Click the *"Command Prompt"* link.
3. Check *"Enable selection coloring"*.
4. Close Tweak UI.

This enables selection coloring on every command-line prompt. You should be able to highlight text, pressing CONTROL-0, CONTROL-1 (or any combination through CONTROL-9) to change the background color of the selected text. For changing the foreground color of the selected text,  press ALT-0, ALT-1 (or any combination through ALT-9).

Comment: Thanks got it working :)

This is the actual behind the scene registry key which is doing the magic.


Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"EnableColorSelection"=dword:00000001